# Why is the conversion to int used, not to bool?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, overload-resolution

I implemented two conversions for a class. One is to bool, one is to int&.

If I implicitly convert to int, it uses the int& conversion, but if I want a bool, it still uses the int& conversion.

```cpp
struct A
{
    operator bool() const;
    operator int&();
};

// trying to call these:
A a;
int  i_test = a; // calls operator int&()
bool b_test = a; // calls operator int&()
```

I understand that a is implicitly converted to int& and then to bool, but why does it take that longer path? How can I avoid it without having to write `a.operator bool()`?

Comment: `a` is not `const`. Hence, none of the operators matches perfectly. This might be the reason why `int& A::operator()` is preferred.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`A a;` declares a non-const object. Since the conversion function is a member function, it accepts an implicit `this` pointer that points at `a`. And overload resolution will choose the non-const qualified member, since it is called on a non-const object.

The fact that it was a conversion to bool that triggered overload resolution is a bit of a red herring. The function's return type (`int&` or `bool`) only makes them candidates for overload resolution (because these will work for converting to `bool`), but it isn't enough to determine the outcome of overload resolution itself.

Comment: And btw. it even does so, when the `const` method is `public` and the corresponding non-`const` method `private`. This once costed me some head-aches and I remember to have found a related Q/A in SO as well.

Comment: @Scheff - Yes, in a world where accessibility could affect overload resolution, we'd likely all be happier (or have other problems to deal with).

Comment: I got it to choose the implementation of the bool conversion by removing its const qualifier. Now i wonder how i could do something like `operator bool() { return operator bool() const; }` to make the conversions from both const a and non-const a use the same function.

Comment: @DanielBauer - One way to share an implementation is to cast `this` into a const object. Either `return std::as_const(*this);` or `return const_cast<A const&>(*this);`.

Comment: It now works as I intended it. I was thinking of that solution, but was not quite sure whether this is how one would do this.